# Is "going to" justified in this case?

Tags: will-vs-going-to

That mailing list is the first place you'**re going to hear** about limited versions, new records on the label and more.

Why" going to "here not will: can we consider that the  mailing list is a plan/ intention? or is it to express that it will happen very soon as in "the bomb is going to explode ?.

I would say that the first should be more plausible .However I think it is only a plan/intention for the writer and the people who have decided to subscribe, not for the others that they are not going to subscribe .

May be  should we understand the sentence  as " if you choose to subscribe,you will be on the mailing list and you are going to hear....... ". In this case it would become an intention / plan . Am I right ?

Comment: The whole thing lacks clarity.

Comment: There are many errors in the question.  Yves, I think the future continuous is being used.

Comment: "am/are/is going to" can frequently be replaced by "will" and that is the case here.

Comment: but the choice of using going to or will  is made by a logic or a rule not by chance

Comment: @Yves Lefol  No thre is no rule for when "will" should be used, and when "going to" should be used.

Answer (score 1):

This use of "going to" is a specil form of the future tense. See [this article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work) and [this one](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_going-to.htm). It is simi8alr to the future progressive (aka future continuous) but not the same.

It indicates that an event is expected to happen, any decision is already made. It is also used for predictions with little doubt. It does not necessarily i8ndicate a plan or intention, although sometimes  it will, because when a plan has been made the choice is often already made of what to do. The use in the question is a pre4diction.

In many case including this one "will" can be substituted for "going to" with no change of meaning, the choice is a matter of style only.

The two statements:

- > the bomb is going to explode
- > the bomb will  explode

have essentially the same meaning. The use of "going to" **may** imply that the event is expected soon, but not always. Consider:

> The sun is going to go out -- after several billion years.

The use of "going to" rather than "will" may put more emphasis on the process, but again not always, and not in the case in the question.

Comment: but when you google about the use of "going to" it is always written that  if the decision has been made before you must use going to or if the event is expected to happen  soon . I think you can use going to with the sun because there is a present evidence (the sciencist discovered that any planets or stars or whatever disappear one day ).

Comment: @Yves Lefol I think you have misunderstood, or found poor sources. "Going to" may be most commonly used in the cases you mention, but in all of them "will" may be substituted. Also "going to" is informal, it is simply not used in formal writing. What specific source or sources are you relying on, please?

Comment: https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplefuture.html for example but may be i haven't well understood

Comment: @Yves Lefol  Note that the use of "going to" in the question is a **prediction** which the englishpage site says may take either form. However I think that site lays out as **rules** what are at best mild tendencies. I would day that every case in which that site uses "wil" a "going to" form may be used freely and properly, and vice versa..